# How to send a data array from an Arduino to vb

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to send data bytes from an Arduino to my visual basic app, but it does not work. I've already tried several solutions but I don't get the values back, I've send to the arduino.

The code I'm using for the visual basic app:

```
    Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim bytes As Integer = 6
    Dim comBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(bytes - 1) {}
    'read the data and store it
    SerialPort1.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes)
    Dim aryReceived(10) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 1 To (bytes - 1)
        aryReceived(i) = comBuffer(i)
        Y(i) = aryReceived(i)
    Next

    a = comBuffer(1)
    b = comBuffer(2)

End Sub

Private Sub Verzenden()

    Dim waardes() As Byte
    waardes = {X(1), X(2), X(3), X(4), X(5), X(6)}

    If SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then

        SerialPort1.Write(waardes, 0, waardes.Length)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub VerzendButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VerzendButton.Click

    X(1) = 10
    X(2) = 11
    X(3) = 12
    X(4) = 13
    X(5) = 14
    X(6) = 15
    Verzenden()

End Sub
```

and the arduino code:

```
int x[9];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() >= 6){
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
      x[i] = Serial.read();
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
      Serial.println(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I send 6 bytes to the arduino with the following values: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 & 15, but sometimes I have to send the bytes twice before the debugger breaks. The values that return in a & b are not the same as I send. The code for sending the bytes works fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You say that what you get back isn't the same: 1. what do you get back?; and 2. Is what you get back at least consistent, even if it's incorrect?  Also, you're using two arrays, X and Y: can you include in your question the code where they're defined?  Finally, you say you sometimes needs to send the bytes twice before the debugger breaks: where is your breakpoint defined?

Comment: I'm very confused about this problem:( i get the following back from my arduino. http://members.home.nl/xanderhuisman/Naamloos.png Maybe sees someone something wrong in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution;) I have Serial.println replaced by Serial.write(x,6). In the Visual Basic app I replaced the reveive event with:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

            For i As Integer = 0 To (Bytes - 1)
                Y(i) = SerialPort1.ReadByte()
            Next
End Sub
```

The Visual Basic app does now receive the data I send from the arduino:)

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint I've set is at the 'end sub' command of the receive event. I often get for a 51 and for b 56, but they're random at other times.

X, Y and a & b are all defined in the public.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim indata As Integer

    Dim Setting As New My.MySettings()
    Dim Opstartmodus As Byte
    Dim OpstartCOMpoort As String

    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String)

    Dim a As Byte, b As Byte, c As Byte, d As Byte, f As Byte, g As Byte

    Dim WaardeVerzenden As Byte, X(9) As Byte, Y(9) As Byte
```

Edit: I've added a delay of 500 microseconds in the arduino code between the receive action and the sens action. Now, After one click on the send button, the debugger breaks immediately. Thats one problem solved! But now, I get always the following patter back: 49,48,13,10,49,49. That totaly doesn't match with the pattern I send to the Arduino:(